# install Ubuntu with existing home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I have an Ubuntu installation in `/dev/sda1` and a separate partition for my home directory in `/dev/sda6`.
I have to reinstall Ubuntu without a home directory in `/dev/sda1` or use `/dev/sda6` as a home partition.

I am familiar with a highly customizable Arch linux, but can I do this (command line install with a pre existing home partition) worth Ubuntu.

Obviously my data in my home partition is vital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While installing you can specify that /dev/sda6 should not be formatted and specify mountpoint as /home. See the older screenshot here, http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-8-04-LTS-84314.shtml